# How to capture index in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to get the index of an element using the `index()` method. I prepared this code, but this function always returns `-1`. I would like to understand:

1. Why this function returns `-1`
2. How to fix it to get the correct index?

If you have some opinion, please let me know.

Thanks

```js
const $days = $(this).find('.day');

$("#calendar .day").on("click", function() {
  console.log("index", $days.index(this));
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id=calendar>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id=1 class=day>1</td>
      <td id=2 class=day>2</td>
      <td id=3 class=day>3</td>
      <td id=4 class=day>4</td>
      <td id=5 class=day>5</td>
      <td id=6 class=day>6</td>
      <td id=7 class=day>7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When you call `$(this).find()`, what do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: _"Why this function return -1"_ -> `console.log(this, $days.length)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build the jQuery list of `.day` elements, it should be

```
const $days = $("#calendar .day");
```

At the global level, `this` will be a reference to `window` and jQuery won't be able to work with that. Thus you got `-1` meaning the element was not in the list.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because `this` in the first line refers to the `window` Element, so `find('.days')` returns nothing. Hence index is always `-1`.

To fix this just use `index()` on the clicked element:

```js
const $days = $("#calendar .day").on("click", function() {
  console.log("index", $(this).index());
});
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div id="calendar">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td id="1" class="day">1</td>
      <td id="2" class="day">2</td>
      <td id="3" class="day">3</td>
      <td id="4" class="day">4</td>
      <td id="5" class="day">5</td>
      <td id="6" class="day">6</td>
      <td id="7" class="day">7</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using jQuery.

```
let index = [...this.parentElement.childNodes].indexOf(this);
```